# porting a library to Android; beginner

Tags: android, wt

I am a newbie in android development but having plans to become an active developer
I had a c++/Java library called Wt. I need to install this library on android.
http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Do I need to port the source code of library?

If yes please point to me a good resource to start with.

Expecting a good helping hand from this community

Comment: Have you read this : http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt#/blog/2010/09/07/wt_on_android

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use native C/C++ code in Android applications, using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) (Native Development Kit)

And it is apparently possible to compile wt for Android, so hopefully not much porting to do!
See http://redmine.emweb.be/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_Android